# How to require PhpStorm to install dependency packages using the PHP in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, mcrypt, laravel-5, homestead

When adding a composer dependency in PhpStorm, I want to use the PHP version that is included with Laravel's Homestead/Vagrant box (this version includes the required mcrypt extension) instead of the standard version that is installed on my Mac OS 10.10. I am able to start Vagrant within PhpStorm and to start an SSH session. However, when I attempt to install a package with the Add Composer Dependency Manager, the wrong PHP version is used, and the install fails.

I assume that I have used the wrong "Path to PHP executable." Both "php" and "/usr/local" have been unsuccessful.

Any suggestions on how to make the Add Composer Dependency Manager install packages using the PHP version that comes with Vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

Using Composer on remote host (by utilizing Remote PHP Interpreter functionality) is not currently supported .. and not even in nearest plans (next version).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23544 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

The workaround is to open Remote SSH session (`Tools | Start SSH session...`) and manually issue command there.